# Binding to Textbox Maxlength field within repeater

Tags: asp.net, .net, repeater

Ive got an issue where the MaxLength field doesnt seem to adhere to the value being set in code-behind.

```
MaxLength='<%#Convert.ToInt32(Eval("AdditionalOptionInfo.MaxFieldLength"))%>'
```

If I set the MaxLength="10" for example it seems to work fine.

EDIT: Whole code

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptList" runat="server">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <ul>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <li>
                <div class="asdf">
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="adsf" CssClass="asdf" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("OptionAvailable")%>' runat="server" OnDataBinding="lnkList_OnDataBinding" OnClientClick="contactDetailOptionClick(this); return false;">
                        <%#Eval("DisplayText")%>
                        <table class="tbox" runat="server" visible='<%#Eval("IsAdditionalInfoApplicable")%>'>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:Label runat="server" CssClass="asdf" Text='<%#Eval("AdditionalOptionInfo.InstructionText")%>' />
                                        <br />
                                        <asp:TextBox placeholder='<%#Eval("AdditionalOptionInfo.PlaceHolderText")%>' RetainValueAfterPostback="true" ellipsis="true" AutoComplete="Off" runat="server" MaxLength='<%#Convert.ToInt32(Eval("AdditionalOptionInfo.MaxFieldLength"))%>'  />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                </asp:LinkButton>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            </ul>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

My implementation after Andrew's suggestion:

```
public int GetMaxLength(object additionalOptionInfo)
    {
        var option = additionalOptionInfo as TypeXYZ<string>;

        return option != null ? option.MaxFieldLength : 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The max lenth eval is still going to be hit if the parent table's visibility is false because all this code is sitting on the front end.

I'd do something like this:

```
MaxLength='<%# GetMaxLength(Eval("AdditionalOptionInfo.MaxFieldLength"))%>'

public string GetMaxLength(object optionInfo)
{
     TypeOfOptionInfo option = (TypeOfOptionInfo) optionInfo;

     if (option != null)
     {
         return optionInfo.MaxFieldLength;
     }
     else
     {
           return "0";
     }
}
```

Comment: I get a null reference exception which is strange because its not supposed to go into that because the IsAdditionalInfoApplicable is false...

Comment: What I could recommend is either setting the max lengh on Item_databound, or calling a method instead of doing an eval. I'd lean towards setting it in Item_databound

Comment: Actually, I thought you were using a repeater at first but now it doesn't look like it. Can you just set the textbox max length in the codebehind maybe?

Comment: Thanks, I've edited my answer to take into account this information.